# JQuery and JSON array - How to check if array is empty or undefined?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I need to pass php array to jquery for some tasks. The php array is created for SESSION and then json_encoded for jquery. After that I'll store that variable to window js namespace in order to use the array in my jquery script.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['mySession'])){
    $json_array = json_encode($php_array);
}

<script>
    <?php echo "window.json_from_php = ".$json_array; ?>
</script>
```

The thing i need to do is to check whether this array exist at all/is empty/undefined before doing anything. The check clause succeeds for 'undefined' operand but not for the rest. How can I check in jquery whether array is empty or not?

This is the output of the json_encoded array after initialization, when there isn't any elements in the $php_array:

```
string '[""]' (length=4)
```

And here is the jquery:

```
$(function() {
        var results = $('#results');
        var js_array = window.json_from_php;
        var count = js_array.length;

        if ((typeof window.json_from_php === 'undefined') || (js_array === null) || (jQuery.isEmptyObject(js_array)) || (count === 0)) {
            $('<p>Array is empty.</p>').appendTo(results);
        }
        else {
            jQuery.each(js_array,function(key,val){
                $('<ul><li id="'+key+'">'+val+'</li></ul>').appendTo(results);                  
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: `[""]` is not an empty array. It's an array with one element: an empty string. empty array = `[]`.

Comment: `string '[""]' (length=4)` What does this line mean? What kind of output is this? It's not a JSON structure.

Comment: Yeah. I don't get it either.

Comment: I see it too. Seems like my php array isn't empty in the first place, but instead the first value is just "". Now, instead of checking if it's empty, I need to check if it's "".

Comment: And the js_array.length/var count in this case is 1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how I check for an empty/null json array.

```
if (js_array == undefined || js_array == null || js_array.length == 0){
    $('<p>Array is empty.</p>').appendTo(results);
}
```

If your json array is `[""]` then you may need to add something like

```
if (js_array == undefined || js_array == null || js_array.length == 0 || (js_array.length == 1 && js_array[0] == ""))
```

Comment: The first two checks are exactly the same.

Comment: I should do it like this: `if (!js_array || !js_array.length){...`

Comment: @Víctor, is `!js_array` the equivalent of `js_array == undefined || js_array == null`?

Comment: @JoeFletch Nope. `!js_array` is equivalent to `js_array == null || js_array === '' || js_array === 0 || js_array === -0 || js_array === false || isNaN(js_array)`.

Comment: @pimvdb, is `js_array == undefined` equivalent to `typeof js_array === 'undefined'` (I will have to check.)

Comment: @JoeFletch Nope. `js_array == undefined` is equivalent to `js_array === undefined || js_array === null` (assuming that `undefined` is indeed the `undefined` value, but that's another story)

Comment: @Joen Fletch: Not exactly, but my point is that `== undefined` disallows `undefined`/`null` just as `== null` does.

Comment: Ok, thanks all for your feedback. I have learned something here and need to rethink some of my logic null/undefined error checking. Should I leave my answer or delete it? I feel like there are good comments here, but I have to go over some things before I edit my answer. Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Please leave your answer (or leave it as edited), since the last operands was a solution for me and the discussion followed is good clarification for the whole issue here.

Comment: @JoeFletch you can learn something interesting about truthy and falsy values here http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/ , it's very useful when working with Javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough:

```
if (typeof js_array === 'undefined' || !js_array.length) {
   $('<p>Array is empty.</p>').appendTo(results);
} else {...}
```